# One person has all the power?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderator, closed-questions, vote-to-close

How is it on other Stack Exchanges it takes multiple votes to close a question, but on Space Exploration one person has the power to close a question even if it is not requested by others?

Answer (score 7):

Muze, all Stack Exchange sites have moderators to supplement the community. A moderator has the ability to perform what we informally refer to as an "insta-close", which immediately closes the question with only one close vote. The community has the ability to override this if they desire by voting to reopen. Many of our users may simply not have the time to read through your long question to see if it is worth closing, that is why we have moderators who volunteer to do this type of activity. For what it's worth, I fully support Kim's action, and I was about to send you a private message anyway.

Also, the moderators are audited by the Stack Exchange Community Team (who are employees of Stack Overflow), and if you have a complaint about a moderator action you can email the Community Team at community@stackexchange.com.

Comment: not a complaint. just curious

Comment: FYI, this is more apparent on small sites, like this one, but can be seen on even SO if one looks carefully enough.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto And the primary reason for that is that the large sites have enough high-rep, interested users to close problematic questions before mods get around to them.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto, called2voyage: Also, the SO mods usually keep to just deleting the worst questions rather than bothering with closing them.

Comment: FWIW, i was also on Christmas patrol. There are few people around at that time and i came around for a while to do some tidying when other people would be busy and it is a bit more awkward.